# Checking if Registry Value exists Visual C++ 2005

Tags: .net, c++, registry, visual-c++-2005

Im trying to code a Visual C++ 2005 routine that checks the registry for certain keys/values.
I have no trouble in writing code using c# but I need it in C++.
Anybody know how to do this using c++ in vs2005.

Many thanks
Tony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here is some pseudo-code to retrieve the following:**

1. If a registry key exists
2. What the default value is for that registry key
3. What a string value is
4. What a DWORD value is

**Example code:**

Include the library dependency: Advapi32.lib

Put the following in your main or where you want to read the values:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Perl", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
bool bExistsAndSuccess (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS);
bool bDoesNotExistsSpecifically (lres == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
std::wstring strValueOfBinDir;
std::wstring strKeyDefaultValue;
GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"BinDir", strValueOfBinDir, L"bad");
GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"", strKeyDefaultValue, L"bad");
```

---

Put these wrapper functions at the top of your code:

```
LONG GetDWORDRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, DWORD &nValue, DWORD nDefaultValue)
{
    nValue = nDefaultValue;
    DWORD dwBufferSize(sizeof(DWORD));
    DWORD nResult(0);
    LONG nError = ::RegQueryValueExW(hKey,
        strValueName.c_str(),
        0,
        NULL,
        reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&nResult),
        &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        nValue = nResult;
    }
    return nError;
}


LONG GetBoolRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, bool &bValue, bool bDefaultValue)
{
    DWORD nDefValue((bDefaultValue) ? 1 : 0);
    DWORD nResult(nDefValue);
    LONG nError = GetDWORDRegKey(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), nResult, nDefValue);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        bValue = (nResult != 0) ? true : false;
    }
    return nError;
}


LONG GetStringRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, std::wstring &strValue, const std::wstring &strDefaultValue)
{
    strValue = strDefaultValue;
    WCHAR szBuffer[512];
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    ULONG nError;
    nError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        strValue = szBuffer;
    }
    return nError;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are Win32 APIs available: take a look at MSDN for [`RegOpenKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724895(VS.85).aspx) and friends (and the [Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724895(VS.85).aspx) in general).

Here is an example of ['Deleting a Key with Subkeys'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724235(VS.85).aspx).